# TypeScript: Constrain generic type parameter passed to a function

Tags: typescript, generics, types, typescript-generics

I have the following generic interface ([full playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgGITAgFtAPABTijgFsBnAGmQCUIyAHAPmQG8AoZZGDbACnqKkyALmSFi5AJSjaDANxsAvmzZgAnvRSEA5qDhhgAexDihyALysOyBIYCu4USDskARtAWKFqjSgDKEETYpuQWVpwAjnbQaqJkYFCg2p7e6prIfoYkEACSkCRh7JzAACZOLu5QKSpp-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-rK9G8KuqzrlA97Nq2djtsg+5HkxZ5Lh+350f+17MW65L3rUoFepsOQgNw3qoM8o5bHxuBwCAahUEZaiMFGaC6a8hyqSS3qgFpE4SJQyBmYw1gAPzOUI1hOBAABuHg+OkfHNBpWm4DpI42fpYHemZpnGRZYTRS8bx2RSiV6pp0DIAyzDeQyyD+UFVRbiW0qZpKWy9qReowDlWlQNWyAkEZdhwIRagSQurG+lF8Xqbl3q1IYjU8dSfGMFQYU-BFeBjRNa7xRZgGcJNRLxchChAA)):

```
interface Fetcher<Params,Resp> {
  fetch(params: Params): Resp;
};
```

It's used as a function parameter with extra constraints applied to its generic parameters:

```
function paginateWithSearch<Params extends (PaginationParams & SearchParams),
  Resp extends SomeItemsResp>(fetcher: Fetcher<Params, Resp>){
    //do something      
}
```

All constraints are represented with simple objects such as:

```
type SearchParams = {
    query: string
};
```

The tricky part is I can't make this constraints actually work in practice:

```
//sample implementation with SearchParams only
const searchFetcher: Fetcher<SearchParams, SomeItemsResp> = {
  fetch: function(): SomeItemsResp {
    throw new Error("Function not implemented.");
  }
}

//Should throw error but works ok - not extending PaginationParams
paginateWithSearch(searchFetcher);
```

The only way that I've come up with is to infer generic parameters with conditional types and pass them to the function manually:

```
//now throws error if inferred manually
paginateWithSearch<FetcherParamsInfer<typeof searchFetcher>, FetcherRespInfer<typeof searchFetcher>>(
  searchFetcher
);
```

I should be missing something as it seems like a straightforward problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While it might be counter-intuitive, it works as expected.

Remember that a callback is not forced to use all provided arguments or their data:

```
declare function convertObjToString(obj: {
  toString: () => string;
}): void;

[new Date()].forEach(convertObjToString);
// Fine, even though it receives a Date with many more properties
```

Therefore it is totally fine passing a `searchFetcher` that takes only a `SearchParams` argument, while it will receive a `PaginationParams & SearchParams` (i.e. an object with *more* properties than necessary for this `searchFetcher`).

We could even pass a callback that takes *no* argument at all:

```
paginateWithSearch({
  fetch() { // No arg at all: okay
    return {
      items: []
    };
  }
});
```

Of course, that means this callback does not use any provided data, hence is bound to return unrelated response (here a fixed empty array for example).

In your sample, it would return something only related to search, disregarding pagination params.

It is up to the caller of `paginateWithSearch` to pass a callback that makes sense for the situation: whether it should be related to both pagination and search, only one of those, or none.

But it cannot use a callback that needs something *beyond* pagination and search: no *sorting* for example.

```
paginateWithSearch({
  // Error: Property 'sorting' is missing in type 'PaginationParams & SearchParams' but required in type '{ sorting: string; }'.
  fetch(params: { sorting: string }) {
    return { items: [] };
  }
})
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgGITAgFtAPABTijgFsBnAGmQCUIyAHAPmQG8AoZZGDbACnqKkyALmSFi5AJSjaDANxsAvmzZgAnvRSEA5qDhhgAexDihyALysOyBIYCu4USDskARtAWKFqjSgDKEETYpuQWVpwAjnbQaqJkYFCg2p7e6prIfoYkEACSkCRh7JzAACZOLu5QKSpp-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-rK9G8KuqzrlA97Nq2djtsg+5HkxZ5Lh+350f+17MW65L3rUoFepsOQgNw3qoM8o5bHxuBwCAahUEZaiMFGaC6a8hyqSS3qgFpE4SJQyBmYw1gAPzOUI1hOBAABuHg+OkfHNBpWm4DpI42fpYHemZpnGRZYTRS8bx2RSiV6pp0DIAyzDeQyyD+UFVRbiW0qZpKWy9qReowDlWlQNWyAkEZdhwIRagSQurG+lF8Xqbl3q1IYjU8dSfGMFQYU-BFeBjRNa7xRZgGcJNRLxch3glBACCGkQKAclyky4mVYAAPKuAAVgAKoYfgJEkvCGLdogimAj3Pdhoh8hYzDxIk2GePyAWGKU3h9LK0oACJzHyAzmjApHyogV7ndAV23Q9T3A9o1oIvCaCgBAVCBa8nb2NoWB6rqLVIMAQVbHAyDw5AxFLG1ZltaRKD0BKmhQAYdAqM+LFSasvAxuS-0sETyCfm5UDaG5updYaohHnAPWisgLVgHYUA8iKevtF8oiDNYtp1soij3uLi4Xr60vWIiuZKqRoj4ILWNqMgADkaLC0kAd6lsJDAGQZDjqAYq+IHQaQWcLkwZemxh64dj0xAUTAC1HZxypAfy8HBi-aiP3JPWAfmkBssCC5H0YSHFdA+O9vpvrGBGybdMW8ggz1rbSiSGwQA)

Comment: So, constraint works as an intersection with an actually provided type, thanks for clarifying it!